# Android MaterialComponents Theme doesn't work properly

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HiCharging.DayNight" parent="Theme.HiCharging.Dark"/>
    <style name="Theme.HiCharging.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HiCharging.DayNight" parent="Theme.HiCharging"/>
    <style name="Theme.HiCharging" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: image1]

When Android is running over white theme, the theme works
However, when I change the theme into dark, the colors on the application cannot be rendered properly. (especially ActionBar)

I tried to modified it according to this image
[image]
However, it doesn't work

Comment: You should try putting your night mode color values in a resource file defined separately for night mode. Right click on res folder and select Android resource file and then choose night mode qualifier for the new colors file.